# How to rewrite this code in Scala using a Functional Programming approach

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Below is code snippet that does some URL normalization. How to rewrite it to use immutable variables only?

Of course, without making it larger or more complex.

```
private def normalizeUrl(url0: String) = {
  var url = url0

  if (url.endsWith("/")) {
    url = url.dropRight(1)
  }

  if (url.indexOf(':') < 0 || 
      url.indexOf(':') == 1) { //windows absolute path
    url = "file:" + url;
  }

  url = url.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

  url
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wanted to chain a bunch of these if/then conditions together to modify a string you could consider adding an implicit class to handle the if/then evaluations like so:

```
object UrlPimping{
  implicit class PimpedUrl(val url:String) extends AnyVal{
    def changeIf(condition:String => Boolean)(f:String => String):String = {
      if (condition(url)) f(url)
      else url      
    }
  }
}

private def normalizeUrl(url: String) = {
  import UrlPimping._

  url.
    changeIf(_.endsWith("/"))(_.dropRight(1)).
    changeIf(u => u.indexOf(':') < 0 || u.indexOf(':') == 1)(u => s"file:$u").
    replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
}
```

This would be overkill if you only had these two conditions to evaluate, but might be nice if you had more and this was a common pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Consider *name* of functional programming!  The whole point is that you replace variables with functions.

```
private def normalizeProtocol(url: String) = 
   if (url.endsWith("/")) url.dropRight(1) else url

private def removeEndingSlash(url: String) = 
  if (url.indexOf(':') < 0 || 
    url.indexOf(':') == 1)  //windows absolute path
    "file:" + url
  else 
    url

private def replaceSlash(url: String) = 
  url.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

private def normalizeUrl(url: String) = 
  replaceSlash(normalizeProtocol(removeEndingSlash(url)))
```

CM Baxter points out, the last function could also be written as

```
private val normalizeUrl = 
   removeEndingSlash _ andThen 
   normalizeProtocol andThen 
   replaceSlash
```

I leave it to you to decide which is more legible.

Comment: Instead of nesting functions together at the end there, you could compose them together like this: `(removeEndingSlash _ andThen normalizeProtocol andThen replaceSlash)(url)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider for instance an intuitive approach with intermediate results, and `if-else` expressions,

```
private def normalizeUrl(url0: String) = {
  val url1 = 
    if (url0.endsWith("/")) url0.dropRight(1) 
    else url0
  val url2 = 
    if (url1.indexOf(':') < 0 || url1.indexOf(':') == 1) "file:" + url1
    else url1

  url2.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
}
```

Note the last expression, `url2` with `replaceAll`, is returned.

Answer (score 2):

What about some refactoring and chaining? Your `var url` is not necessary here.

I think this would work:

```
private def normalizeUrl(url: String) = {
  (if (url.indexOf(':') < 0 || url.indexOf(':') == 1) {
    "file:"
  } else {
    ""
  }) + (if (url.endsWith("/")) {
    url.dropRight(1)
  } else {
    url
  }).replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
}
```

Of course, for better readability, I would suggest the use of something like this:

```
private def normalizeUrl(url: String) = {
  val prefix  = if (url.indexOf(':') < 0 || url.indexOf(':') == 1) "file:" else ""
  val noSlash = if (url.endsWith("/")) url.dropRight(1) else url

  (prefix + noSlash).replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
}
```

Don't be afraid to use more than one val's. :)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use the Reader Monad and map the functions over it:

```
val normalizeUrl: Reader[String, String] = Reader[String, String](s => s)
  .map(url => if (url.endsWith("/")) { url.dropRight(1) } else url)
  .map(url => if (url.indexOf(':') < 0 || url.indexOf(':') == 1) "file:" + url else url)
  .map(url => url.replaceAll("\\\\", "/"))
```

Then just call it like any function:

```
normalizeUrl("some\\\\url")
```

I think I would prefer elm's solution though

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one. You write tests for reach of your functions ( `removeEndSlash`, `removeSlashes` and `removeSlashes`

```
def normalizeURL(url: String) = {
    def removeEndSlash(u: String): String = if (u.endsWith("/")) u.dropRight(1) else u
    def isFile(u: String): String = {
      val idx = u.indexOf(':')
      if (idx < 0 || idx == 1)
        "file:" + u
      else
        u
    }
    def removeSlashes( u : String ) = u.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")

    removeSlashes(isFile(removeEndSlash(url)))

  }
```